# Setting values to MultiIndex DataFrame is getting slow while running

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a `11729 rows × 8 columns` DataFrame, I'd like to convert it to a `11729 × 30 × 8` matrix with MultiIndex, which 30 means every 30 lines of 11729 rows from 0 to `11728 - 30`

for a shorter example:

the origin 2d DataFrame looks like:

```
      col0   col1
0        1      2
1        3      4
2        5      6
3        7      8
4        9     10
```

the 3d MultiIndex DataFrame which I want to get would looks like:

```
           col0    col1
0    c0       1       2
     c1       3       4
     c2       5       6
1    c0       3       4
     c1       5       6
     c2       7       8
2    c0       5       6
     c1       7       8
     c2       9      10
```

which means (0,c0)~(0,c2) from 0~2 rows in origin DataFrame, (1,c0)~(1,c2) from 1~3 rows in origin DataFrame, (2,c0)~(2,c2) from 2~4 rows in origin DataFrame.

I'm using the following code to convert the origin 2d DataFrame to MultiIndex 3d DataFrame:

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]],
                             labels=[[],[]],
                             names=['', ''])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_index, columns=origin_df.columns)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, len(origin_df) - (n - i)):
        print("i{}/n{},j{}".format(i, n, j))  # print progress
        df.loc[(j, 'c%d' % i), :] = origin_df.loc[origin_df.index[j]].tolist()
for i in range(n, len(origin_df)):
    df.loc[(i, 'y'), :] = origin_df.loc[origin_df.index[i]].tolist()
return df
```

My problem is the insertion speed is getting slow while running.
At first the progress output is fast, but getting slower and slower.
How could I optimize this operation?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be adding one by one. Here's what I would do:

```
# toy data:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11792*8).reshape(-1,8));
window = 30
new_len = len(df) - window + 1

# create new dataframe, ignoring the index
new_df = pd.concat(df.iloc[i:i+window] for i in range(new_len))

# modify the index
new_df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(new_len), [f'c{i}' for i in range(window)]])
```

That took about 1 second on a 6600k. With your sample data, the output is:

```
      col0  col1
0 c0     1     2
  c1     3     4
  c2     5     6
1 c0     3     4
  c1     5     6
  c2     7     8
2 c0     5     6
  c1     7     8
  c2     9    10
```